# Is there way to make nav-bar responsive by using only HTML & CSS?

Tags: html, css, nav

I am quite new to html and css. I am struggling to make the nav bar to be responsive with my main content, but it seems to me only the container be responsive when the screen size is changed somehow. I had also try `width: 100%` & `@media` but I do not know where i went wrong and the nav elements just disapears.

Here is the page i am working on:`https://codepen.io/kippulainen04/pen/YzZYqLz`
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

nav elements are just hidden inside your header element. For a simple solution you can render the items of header vertically in smaller screens.

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  #header, #header ul{
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  #header ul li{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
}
```

But the most common solution for this is to hide nav elements under a hamburger icon. Please check this [tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_mobile_navbar.asp) from w3schools